# PHP, Ajax - $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] not changing and file not uploading

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to use ajax along with php to inform the user of the progress as a file is uploading. However now when i submit my form the file isn't in $_FILES and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] isn't changing from GET to POST. Am i just missing some code or did i just make a mistake?

Here's most of my code:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>
                Outer Haven - Video Upload
                </title>

<link href='css/videoUpload.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'lib/videoAjax.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <br/>
<form action='/OuterHaven/index.php' id='uploadForm' target='hiddenFrame' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='hidden' value='uploadForm' name=''>
        <label for='file'>File name:</label>
        <input type='text' name='fileName' id='fileName' value=''/>
        <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='4194304'>
        <br/>
        <input type='file' name='myVideo'>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='uploadSubmit'>
</form>
<div id='barBlank'>
        <div id='barColour'></div>
</div>
<iframe id='hiddenFrame' name='hiddenFrame' src='about:blank'></iframe>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        (function(){document.getElementById('uploadForm').onsubmit = startUpload;})();
</script>
        </body>
</html>
```

[AJAX / Javascript](http://pastebin.com/95Hyk87P)

[PHP](http://pastebin.com/iTX48XyN)

Comment: If you don't use the ajax does the file show up in the $_FILES variable?

Comment: I ended up solving it, it was the script at the end of the html. It doesn't function and was left over from a previous iteration. Removing it solved the issue.